# Swift When saving constants what's the performance differences between Enum.rawValue and static constant property?

Tags: swift

When saving constants, for example string keys, what's the performance differences between using enum's rawValue and using a static constant property?
Are they effectively the same to the compiler when the full module optimization is turned on?

For example,

```swift
enum Schema: String {
    case createdAt = "createdAt"
}

// Here As namespace only, similarly if we use struct/protocol.
enum Schema { 
    static let createdAt = "createdAt"
}
```

Further, if we add a prefix, will they still be identical to the compiler?

```swift
enum DynamicSchema: String {
    case createdAt = "createdAt"

    var prefixed: String { 
        "com.blah.bleb." + self
    }
}

enum StaticSchema { 
    static let prefixString = "com.blah.bleb."
    
    static let createdAt = "createdAt"
}

// For example,
UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: DynamicSchema.createdAt.prefixed)

UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: StaticSchema.prefixString + StaticSchema.createdAt)
```

Comment: These mean different things, so you choice shouldn't be decided by performance, it should be decided by the semantics you want. If you just want a kitchen drunk drawer to hold miscellaneous constants, then a caseless enum would be appropriate. But if you want exclusivity checking, and you're expressing relationships between cases, then an enum with cases would be better. In this case, I think it's a toss-up.

Comment: Are you sure these keys need to be prefixed? Aren't they in their own dedicate plist file that belongs sole to your app?

Comment: @Alexander the UserDefaults is used for the purpose of demonstration and its an abstracted question related to the language and compiler and not bond to a specific frameworkd/api. Well, t.b.h. this question has been in my mind for a very long time, so far all my frameworks/apis using the static approach, that sacrifices ergonomics.

Comment: A hint in terms of performance, is that As per WWDC2016 Understanding Swift Performance, the String is actually heap-allocated which participate in reference counting, where an Enum with String as rawValue is still stack-allocated. Therefore, when passing them around, Enum has the advantage of avoiding reference-counting.

Answer (score 1):

Using 'compiler explorer' at godbolt.org, then choose swift as the language, set the compiler options to whatever optimization level, add the code under test. The disassembly is shown.

The static let variant is quite different to the enum case variant, static let is about 9x shorter

Comment: Yes, because the enum conforms to `Equatable`, `Hashable`, `RawRepresentable`, and so on, and it's also storing the metadata necessary for reflection (e.g. through `Mirror`), though this doesn't necessarily tell you much about the performance

Comment: Indeed, I only mean they're not "effectively the same to the compiler"

Comment: I'm not sure about that. If you toss in whole module optimization, I would expect that these unused compiler conformances would be pruned

Comment: "swiftc -emit-sil -whole-module-optimization" for the different variants and then compare?

Comment: thanks for looking up those flags for me. I have to play around with it. It's a bit tricky to make a simple but realistic scenario to demonstrate what the real output might be, because in most cases, the compiler erases my whole program lol. But if I rely too much on the specifics of the enum, then I force it to keep all the related-machinary